# Can I build a progressive web app showing a website which is not my own?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am currently creating a chrome-extension, which re-styles a website(not my own). I would also like to create a progressive web app, which can be downloaded from my site, where people can view this third party website, but with my custom CSS and JavaScript. Is this possible to build?

Regards
Benjamin

Comment: Mark the question answered if it solves your question or add comment on what is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Manifest and service worker file should be present in the actual websites location along with other PWA features. You can fake it with an PWA app frame having iframe. But due to cross origin requests, that wont help you build a PWA for 3rd party either.